# how do I know what order to write $-27x^{12} y^3 z^6$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing some algebra problems that are fairly straight forward except that I don't know what the rules are concerning what order to list the variables with exponents in i.e. $$ -(x^3yz^2)^3 (-3x)^3 $$ my answer $$-27 x^{12}y^3 z^6$$  what the rule on the order to list I know that it should look like $$27 y^3z^6x^{12}$$ Please help!

Comment: There is no particular rule regarding the order of variables. Though generally alphabetical order is preferred.

Comment: but in most of these cases they list in some other order ie y^3 z^6 x^12 I need to know this was the correct order over alphabetical

Comment: There is no reason except that *they* decided to write it that way.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs  I believe the initial negative was inside the parentheses and not preceding the parentheses as you have it? Perhaps it was ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Math StackExchange.  As you suspect, there is no "why".  However, in your second answer, the 27 is positive whereas the first is negative.  This is why the second is correct while the first is incorrect. The cube of -1 is negative and the cube of -3 is negative.  The product of two negatives is positive.

Comment: I understand the negative vs the positive but Aleks freaks out if the variables with exponents are not in an order it prefers.  which in this case seems to be by exponent value but in previous problem it was alphabetical

Comment: Actually, I happen to teach using ALEKS extensively.  It doesn't care which order the variables are typed into the answer as far as I have ever seen.

Comment: k will try this one more time and see how it goes thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are different monomial ordering in multivariate polynomials: "lexicographical order", "total degree order", "graded lexicographic order", etc. see for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order, [Monomial orders for multivariate polynomials](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner%2FMonomialOrders).

Within a monomial the variables can also be written either lexicographically or degree sorted (e.g. ascending as in your second example).